# Database structure for a mail list

Tags: mysql

I am designing a database structure for a mail list
The data i need to record is the mail receiver data:

Since the mail receiver data is not predefine, 
it cause a problem:
for example: 
some of the receiver have name, mail address, phone no
while the others have name, birthdate, mail address, gender, etc...

```
So my design is like this:
Table Receiver:
PK: ReceiverID
    AttributeID
    DataID

Table Attribute:
PK: AttributeID
    AttributeName

Table Data:
PK: DataID
    DataContent

A example of one receiver is:
Receiver: 1 1 1
Attribute: 1 mailAddress
Data:1 test@test.com

Receiver: 1 2 2
Attribute: 2 Name
Data:2 Tony
```

This cause a problem because i want to check the data field type and length, what is a better database design? Sorry about the poor description, i would clarify it if you are confused .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its *impossible* per definition to define datatypes for unknown attributes. This is just how databases work.

I understand you want the birthday to be a DATETIME column. (and possibly other "special" datatypes for a few other attributes)

I cannot believe the impossiblity to predefine the available attributes - they are limited. just go ahead and define a list of possible attributes.

A better database design would be to just create a receiver table that contains all possible fields and allows them to be NULL. Using the database as a "generic storage" for arbitrary attributes is bad practice when not necessery.

your table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE maillist_receivers (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, 
  firstname VARCHAR(128), 
  lastname VARCHAR(128), 
  phone VARCHAR(128), 
  birthdate DATETIME, 
  ...
)
```

And your data could look like this:

```
id     firstname      lastname     email            phone      birthdate
1      Max            Power        mp@foo.com       NULL       21.12.2012
2      John           Doe          john@doe.com     555-1234   NULL
```

- It performs better
- the datatypes are well defined
- You can check in your application code if a value is NULL and handle that accordingly. (as in: do not send birthday card, ..)
- it is clean - you can read the plain data in a database browser

Comment: Thanks and the problem is  : because it is a system for different user
so that eg.  phone attribute is for userA, while birthdate is only for B

Comment: That will cause a lot of null record if a user has a lot of receiver but only need email attribute.
e.g. 
id 1 null null test@test.com null null 

 Would it be a problem?

Comment: i don't see a problem with that.

Comment: Besides, this will cause a problem if USER A want phone is required field but USER B  don't want it be required

Comment: I can't notice who want a field eg. phone required and who do not want phone field required

Comment: you can check this on application level. use a seperate table to define which customer requires which field .. (ideally, you would have the same field names in your table `customer_required_attributes` defined as boolean, true = mandatory, false = optional)

Comment: is it :
Table Require 
PK ReqID,   
   AttributeName,
   IsRequire